# How can jade attributes be set for Dynamically click generated variables in Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug, bootstrap-modal

I have returned a valid JSON through mongoose to my Jade file, the JSON named `things` looks like this,

```
[{
   _id: ObjectId("7788h356i0909v7863b75999"),
   important: "Critical123",
   property:[{name: "Test456"},{name: "Test789"},{name: "Test101112"}]
 },
 {
   _id: ObjectId("7788h356i0909v7863b75908"),
   important: "Critical",
   property:[{name: "TestNew"},{name:"TestNewlyOpened"}]
  }
]
```

I have a certain jade file spitting out details of a page I wanted like below

Basically when you click on glyphicon-plus-sign, I am opening a modal window

```
if thing
   each something in thing
          tr.odd.gradeX(id="firstRow" rowspan="2")
             td.imp(type="button") #{something.important}
               a.glyphicon-plus-sign(id="#{something._id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg")
```

My Modal is declared in the samefile below as

```
.modal.fade.bs-example-modal-lg(id="modalBoxSomething" tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='myLargeModalLabel', aria-hidden='true', style='display: none;')
  .modal-dialog.modal-lg
    .modal-content
      .modal-header#headerModal
        h4#myLargeModalLabel.modal-title
        button.close(id="modalCloseButton" type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-label='Close')
          span(aria-hidden='true') &times;           
      .modal-body
        .somethingDetails.col-md-6.col-lg-6
         if property
            each nameProperty in property 
              p#propertyName #{nameProperty.name}
```

This doesn't work. Can I loop over `nested sub items` in an `array` for a specific item `click event`?

I want to repeat the values of `property` array for each `something` in this `modal window`.

Or Should I write a `Javascript` to do this?

```
for(var k=0; k<things.length; k++){
      for(var m=0; k<things[k].property.length; m++){
         $('#propertyName').append('<p>'+JSON.stringify(things[k].property[m].name+'</p>');
      }
}
```

What is the best practice here? The `Javascript` solution works, But it would be great if what I am trying to achieve in `Jade` works sublimely.

Comment: Define "This doesn't work.". How do you pass the data to your template? What is `property`? Jade logs the errors (_if any_), why don't you use it? Also you are generating invalid markup. IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I loop over nested sub items in an array for a specific item click event?

Of course you can. Jade templates are rendered using JavaScript and you can also use raw JavaScript in your templates by using `-` in the beginning of the line. If your JavaScript code does what you want you can move it's logic into your template file.

> What is the best practice here?

Using Jade.

It's not clear what `property` is in your template file. If you expect Jade to know that it's a property of an array of objects this is not the case. You need to  iterate through the array and then iterate through `property` array of each object element, i.e. 2 nested loops.

Assuming you have used `things` identifier for the array:

```
each thing, index in things 
  h2.sample= thing.important
  each item in thing.property
     p.propertyName= item.name
```

Note that IDs must be *unique* otherwise you have generated an invalid markup.